# Notepad++ syntax highlighter for LLVM assembly

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++, llvm

Are there any syntax highlighters for LLVM assembly?

Answer (score 4):

None that I know of. But you can always create your own using Notepad++'s User Defined Language framework. See [this](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/resources.html) and [that](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files) for more details.

Comment: Sure, I just wished somebody had already done it, but thx! ;)

Comment: Hehe.. Well, if you do create some, don't forget to share! I am sure people will help you to improve it and drive it to a perfection!

Comment: @user405725, here it is https://github.com/Naios/notepad_llvm

Answer (score 1):

There is a [highlighting file for Vim](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/utils/vim/llvm.vim). At the very least, you can look up a list of keywords there.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is: https://github.com/Naios/notepad_llvm

To install: download and then Notepad++ > Define your own language... > Import > llvm_ir.xml

Comment: It failed to import on my npp version 6.5.1